# How to determine elements count in boost.preprocessor tuple`s?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

How to determine elements count in [boost.preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/tuples.html) tuple`s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost 1.49 already has BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE macro

Answer (score 2):

You don't. That's why every macro that uses tuples requires you to specify the size of the tuple. You could try doing something based on a 2 tuple where the first value is the size of the second:

```
#define MyTuple (2,(a,tuple))
#define MyTupleSize( S_ ) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM( 2, 0, S_ )
#define GetMyTuple( S_, I_ ) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM( MyTupleSize(S_), I_, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, S_ ) )
MyTupleSize( MyTuple ) // this is '2'
GetMyTuple( MyTuple, 1 )// this is 'tuple'
```

Unfortunately there is no way to determine the size of a tuple other than to know it or store it in a known sized tuple or in a list etc.